# Concavity and inflection points??

Tags: calculus

I need to find the open intervals on which $f(x)$ is concave upward, concave downward, and the coordinates of the points of inflection.

[image]

I thought the answer was ...

Concave up: $(0, 2)\cup(5, 8)$

Concave down: $(2, 5)$

Points of Inflection: $(2, 2), (5, 2)$

But these answers aren't right! Why??

Comment: Would help to know what the function is.  And what are the answers, because everything here is a little bit open to questioning as far as details and all.

Comment: I put the picture of the function there...the function as an equation wasn't given. And I don't know the answers that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: Why do you say the answers aren't right?

Comment: I have to enter them online and it says at least one of my answers is incorrect :(

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like $(2,5)$.  Try $(2,4)\cup(4,5)$

Comment: Omg that was it thank you so much I love you